# Split my list up by financial institution

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I need some help with my problem.  I have created a list of all my investments but now I need to seperate them by financial institution.  I am trying to print a report out that will have all the investments for each financial institution on a seperate page but I am having trouble splitting them up.

For example what I want is:

TD Bank
- all investments for TD from my query

- next page -

Scotia Bank
-all investments for Scotia from my query

etc

The following is my views.py that has the query and adding all the information to my list.

Can anyone help me find a way to split it up so I can have them seperated by financial institution?

```
def confirmations_report(request, *args, **kwargs):
from investments.models import Investment, InvestmentManager
from reports.forms import ConfirmationsForm
import ho.pisa as pisa
import cStringIO as StringIO
import os.path
confirm_letter_list = []
context = {}

if request.POST:
    form = ConfirmationsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
        investments = Investment.objects.all().filter(contract_no = "",maturity_date__range=(start_date, end_date)).order_by('financial_institution')
        for i in investments:
            confirm_letter_list.append({
                'fi':i.financial_institution,
                'fi_address1': i.financial_institution.address1,
                'fi_address2': i.financial_institution.address2,
                'fi_city': i.financial_institution.city,
                'fi_prov': i.financial_institution.state_prov,
                'fi_country': i.financial_institution.country,
                'fi_postal': i.financial_institution.postal,
                'primary_owner': i.plan.get_primary_owner().member,
                'sin': i.plan.get_primary_owner().member.client.sin,
                'type': i.product.code,
                'purchase_amount': i.amount,
                'purchase_date': i.start_date,
            })
            context['confirmlist'] = confirm_letter_list
        context['inv'] = investments
    if request.POST.has_key('print_report_submit'):
        context['show_report'] = True
        context['mb_logo'] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../../media/images/mb_logo.jpg")
        html = render_to_string('reports/admin/confirm_report_print.html', RequestContext(request,context))
        result = StringIO.StringIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
        response = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=unreceived-confirmations.pdf'
        return response

else:
    form = ConfirmationsForm()

context['form'] = form
return render_to_response('reports/admin/confirm_report.html', RequestContext(request, context))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-examples.html) with a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_list = defaultdict(list)
for i in investments:
   my_list[i.financial_institution].append({ ... })
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
{% for i in my_list.iteritems %}
   Institution : {{ i.0 }}
   {% for z in i|slice:"1:" %}
     Total Items for {{ i.0 }} : {{ z|length }}
     {% for d in z }}
        {{ d.fi_address1 }}
        ....
     {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is a simplified example:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['hello'].append({1:'One', 2:'Two'})
>>> for i in d.iteritems():
...    print i[0]
...    for z in i[1:]:
...     print z
... 
hello
[{1: 'One', 2: 'Two'}]
```

As you can see the inner loop contains the list of dicts that you have added, so you need to adjust your loop logic accordingly.

Comment: Then how would I go about displaying on the template?

Comment: Well they will be sorted by the institution name, so you would simply step through the list by the key (which is the primary key of the institution). See update.

Comment: Hmm I know seem to be getting this error when trying to compile my template `Caught TypeError while rendering: 'long' object is not iterable` and its pointing to `{% for i in my_list %}`

Comment: I've expanded the answer with a minimal example. You should be able to take it from there.